# Big O notation times zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Consider a real-valued sequence $\{h_n\}_n$ such that $$(\star) \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}h_n=0$$ In order to show that $0*O(h_n^2)=0$ do we need to use assumption $(\star)$? Why?

Comment: What is  $0*O(h_n^2)$ supposed to mean in Big O notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $O\!\left(h_n^2\right)$ is a set of sequences
$$
O\!\left(h_n^2\right)=\left\{\left\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}:\exists A,N_a\gt0:\forall n\ge N_a,\left|a_n\right|\le A\left|h_n^2\right|\right\}
$$
If by $0$ you mean a sequence $\left\{b_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$, then for some $N_b$, we have by definition $n\ge N_b\implies\left|b_n\right|\le1$. Then, for $n\ge\max(N_a,N_b)$
$$
\left|a_nb_n\right|\le A\left|h_n^2\right|
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left\{a_nb_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\in O\!\left(h_n^2\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot; however by $0$ I mean zero, hence $b_n=0$ $\forall n$.

Comment: If one is going for rigor, as this answer apparently does, then, in the definition, "$\exists A>0,\forall n\in\mathbb N$" should read "$\exists A>0,\exists k\in\mathbb N,\forall n\ge k$".

Comment: @Did: Yes, since $h_n$ might be $0$ at some finite point, this is true.

Comment: "for functions, this is necessary. However, this is not necessary for sequences." Huh? Of course it is, for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @Did: Yes. I realized what you were saying. $h_n$ is not like $\frac1n$ and might vanish at some finite point, thus $O(h_n^2)$  is different from something like $O\!\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$. I edited my comment and answer.

Comment: @STF: that case is handled by this answer, too. That is, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}0=0$.